# Finder not appearing when uploading files

Tags: finder, google-chrome, monterey

Version: macOS 12.01

Browser: Google Chrome

My finder isn't opening to allow me to upload files to any website or service. This only happens when I click the "upload" or "attach" buttons on a site (such as gmail). Finder functions as normal when I open it manually, or when I try to upload on Safari. For troubleshooting, I've tried force-restarting finder.

To reiterate, when I try clicking "upload" in any website in Chrome, absolutely nothing happens and the Finder window does not appear.

Comment: I wouldn't expect any Finder window to open on an Upload call from a browser, I'd expect a modal dialog in front of the app making the call. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean, I think. Where it looks like Finder but technically it's just a dialog box